# copying data from array to vector c++ c99

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, microcontroller

i have 2 classes working with communication data 
in one class the array information is stored as a fixed array

```
uint8 msg[512];   
//fixed array to reduce mem fragmentation on target
```

i want to memory copy this to a vector in the 2nd class

```
vector<uint16> schbuff;  
// not set offend so mem fragmentation on such a issue
```

i am using  c++ c99 so and Im looking for a way not to have pass each element to the new container

if they are both the same type it would not be such a issue but imm new to c++ so any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's `c++ c99`? Are you talking about `c++11`, `c++03`, or `c++98`?

Comment: To convert an array of uint8 to uint16 you will need a for loop. That's a C problem rather than C++ specific. Do you need help with that part, or just writing to a vector?

Comment: Do you want the uint16 to contain one uint8 with padding, or two uint8 packed into one uint16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>   // for copy
#include <iterator>    // for begin, end, back_inserter

std::copy(std::begin(msg), std::end(msg), std::back_inserter(schbuff));
```

Comment: He mentions memory fragmentation as an issue. You should reserve the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor

```
vector<uint16> schbuff( msg, msg + 512 );
```

Or can use member function assign

```
schbuff.assign( msg, msg + 512 );
```

Or can use member funcrion reserve. For example

```
vector<uint16> schbuff;
schbuff.reserve( 512 );

std::copy( msg, msg + 512, std::back_inserter( msg ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const int msg_size = 512;
uint8 msg[msg_size];
vector<uint8> msg_vec;
msg_vec.assign(msg, msg + msg_size);
```

Edit: just noticed the types are different. But I will keep the answer for example of how to put in vector.

Comment: You can still use `assign` even if the types are different.